# Switching Between Order And Autocracy

Tags: civilization-5

Related: [What is the effect of switching between conflicting social policies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/what-is-the-effect-of-switching-between-conflicting-social-policies)

I know that switching between conflicting social policies results in a few turns of anarchy, but I was wondering about the effect of switching between two maxed-out policies.

Maxing the Autocracy social policy results in a 50-turn attack bonus for all units. I would assume this means that the effects is gone after 50 turns. However, if I switch to the Order social policy and then switch back to Autocracy, do I gain the attack bonus for another 50 turns?

Comment: Interesting question. It looks like a something to exploit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you max the Autocracy tree, you gain an instant 30-turn attack bonus (at least in the game I played - this may depend on your game speed.) This is denoted by a "Temp Attack Bonus" entry in the unit's attack preview pane:

[image]

This attack bonus *stays active* if you switch to another conflicting policy tree, such as Freedom or Order.  This is the attack bonus still active, even though I've switched policies:

[image]

Once it runs out, it is gone for good.  There doesn't appear to be a way to exploit this in the way you specify in your question.