# Cilivization Production times change after turn?

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing Civ 5 and during one of my turns all of my production times changed drasticly. one of my soldier sets went from 4 turns to over 30 turns this is after I chose it.

This happened to all 4 of my cities. I would choose a monument and it went from 10 turns to over 30. How do I get this back to correct time?

Comment: Did you perhaps start a revolution to change civics that turn?

Answer (score 9):

I can think of several options that can affect your empire-wide production:

1. A golden age just ended
2. Your happiness is so low you entered the "very unhappy" stage, which halves your production output
3. You chose a conflicting social policy tree and your empire has entered [anarchy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/what-is-the-effect-of-switching-between-conflicting-social-policies)
4. You have a railroad network which was suddenly disconnected, so you lost the +25% boost in all cities
5. Your AI decided to switch citizens to something else (e.g. gold, if you need it desperately)